# How can i create a recursive method that does the exp of n but returns a String n number of times in Java

Tags: java, recursion

So i'm doing an exercise but i'm having a bad time with recursive methods.

I want the method `starPower` to return the power of 2 to the n  in asterisks ("*") but i get a Stack Overflow.

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Here is what i have so far:

```
public static String starPower(int n){
    String str = "*";
    if (n<0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n has an invalid value");
    if (n==0)
        {return str;
        }     
    return str + starPower( Math.pow(2,n-1));
}
```

Comment: When you want the recursive to stop? if n == 0 or what?

Comment: How can this code compile?  `Math.pow` returns a `double`.

Comment: So even assuming you cast the `Math.pow` result to an `int`, you'd have `starPower(3)` calling `starPower(4)`, which calls `starPower(8)`, which calls `starPower(128)`, which calls `starPower(170141183460469231731687303715884105728)`--which Java can't do.  But `starPower(2)` calls `starPower(2)` which calls `starPower(2)` over and over until you get a stack overflow.  Look at your logic and see what it's doing.

Comment: @Tommy Of course I knew that.  My comment was about the fact that the poster posted code that doesn't compile, despite the fact that the error he's asking about happened at run time.  So obviously he didn't post the same code that he was asking about.  That causes obvious problems.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Math.pow()`. Your method is supposed to be recursive and use simple operations.

I will not give you the code, but explain how it should work. First, here are the expected results:

```
starPower(0) = "*"                                 // 2^0 = 1 stars
starPower(1) = "**"                                // 2^1 = 2 stars
starPower(2) = "****"                              // 2^2 = 4 stars
starPower(3) = "********"                          // 2^3 = 8 stars
starPower(4) = "****************"                  // 2^4 = 16 stars
starPower(5) = "********************************"  // 2^5 = 32 stars
starPower(6) = "****************************************************************"
 . . .
```

As you can see, the result if `starPower(n)` is double<sup>1</sup> the result of `starPower(n - 1)`. That is your simple recursion.

<sup>1) By double, I mean double the length, i.e. the string concatenated with itself.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have to think recursively, which is pretty difficult.  If you concatenated the results of two function calls for `n-1`, you'd have two halves, making a whole.  Notice however that since calling the function twice with the same input would yield the same output twice.  So you can help lessen the burden on the stack by only calling once and using the result twice.

Try to visualize it like this for an example of calling `starPower(3)`.  It calls `starPower(2)` and concatenates the result of that with itself.  Calling `starPower(2)` calls `starPower(1)` and concatenates the result of that with itself.  `starPower(1)` calls `starPower(0)` and concatenates the result of that with itself.

`starPower(0)` always returns `"*"`; it's the base case.  You can now build up from here.  `starPower(1)` takes two of them and pastes them together making `"**"`.  `starPower(2)` concatenates two of those to make `"****"`.  There's a pattern emerging for you now hopefully.  Lastly, `starPower(3)` takes two of those and concatenates them to make the final result of `"********"`, which is 8, or 2³, asterisks.

```
3:        ********
2:    ****        ****
1:  **    **    **    **
0: *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
```

Here's the modified code implementing that solution.

```
public static String starPower(int n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("n has an invalid value");
  }

  if (n == 0) {
    return "*";
  }

  String halfResult = starPower(n - 1);

  return halfResult + halfResult;
}
```

Comment: Only making the recursion once does not "lessen the burden on the stack". The maximum stack depth is the same. It greatly improves the performance, by making `n` recursive calls, rather than `2^n` recursive calls, but that has nothing to do with the "stress" on the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the pattern of the outputs in your problem to solve it.

if you can find a relation between input and output in each case of `n` you could solve it.this way of thinking is called **Reverse Engineering**.

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261309/5169186) said in his answer from the test cases you can conclude that `starPower(n)` is double the result of `starPower(n - 1)`:

```
starPower(0) = "*"                                
starPower(1) = "**"                                
starPower(2) = "****"
```

so you only need to double the result of `"*"` in each recursive call:

```
public static String starPower(int n){
      if (n < 0){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("n has an invalid value");
      }
      if (n==0){
         return "*";
      }     
      return starPower(n-1) + starPower(n-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(starPower(3));
}
```

Output:

```
********
```